# Behavior of jQuery's append inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm confused about the behavior of jQuery's `.append()` method in a for loop.

This code attaches and displays the file names on the div element. It works fine, but I'm reading the code, and I'm in the understanding that the file name gets appended in sequence/one after the other as it loops. But it appears like they get displayed together once the loop finishes. I also tried to intercept it with an alert to check.

Why does it happen this way?

```
$("#fileInput").on("change", function() {
    $(".input-feedback").html('');

    for(var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        var file = this.files[i];
        console.log(file.name);

        alert('test');
        $(".input-feedback").append("<p>"+ file.name +"</p>");
    }
});
```

Comment: That's not the case. they are appended one at a time. you don't see the difference as loading time is very minimal

Comment: The browser doesn't re-render the page every time you call append. It waits until the script has finished and then redraws the page. Otherwise it would be extremely slow with no practical benefit.

Comment: yea jquery might also only append just before frame render, to reduce re-renderings.

Comment: @JoelHarkes hum no. jQuery won't do that. When you do modification to the DOM, they are done synchronously. Otherwise it would be a complete mess... What is delayed is the reflow (i.e recalc of all the layout, box-sizes etc.) which can also occur synchronously in some cases, and the repaint. But except for synchronous reflow, these are handled by the browser, never by jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Files are added one at a time but...

Usually browsers wait until js code run is completelly finished and js is idle waiting for events in order to perform the dom rendering (it depends on browser, the type of event which you are running from and on DOM changes applied).

If you want to see how each item is added for sure, then best way is run code asyncronously with setTimeout or setInterval.